# Mobile bootstrap navbar button not collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this has been posted tons of times but I still cannot find the solution. I have tried viewing it on mobile and by shrinking the browser but all the nav collapse button isn't "collapsing." I followed the guidance provided by other posts but none have worked. I have set the `data-target` to the correct ID and I have all of the scripts sourced.

My code:

```css
nav ul li{
    width:117px;
}
nav{
    box-shadow: 15px 0px 45px #1f2021;
}
.navbar-fixed-top{
    position:absolute!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:1261px)" href="css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:781px) and 
    (max-width:1260px)" href="css/tablet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:780px)" href="css/mobile.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script 
        src = "../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js" > < \/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="ms-icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="logoSpace">
        <center> <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"><br /></center>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria- controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" 
    aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About  <span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="roster.html">Roster  <span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="history.html">History  <span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a></li>
            <li style="width:130px;float:left;"><a href="schedule.html">Schedule <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list">
    </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos  <span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="videos.html">Videos  <span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-film"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="coaches.html">Coaches  <span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-book"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact  <span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-send"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be collapsing fine for me on https://www.bootply.com/ZDsDf2k3F2

Comment: @RobertC That's interesting. Does it seem look like I'm missing any JS files?

Comment: I'm not sure.  When I copy/pasted the `<nav>` into Bootply it displayed the toggle properly, but didn't actually dropdown.  When I corrected some formatting issues (made sure relevant code was on a single line) and ran the code again it collapsed and dropped down w/o issue.

I'd check your paths to ensure CSS/JS is loading, and I'd check your formatting to see if you have some weird characters (like faux spaces) mucking things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few misplaced tags. Like missing `</div>` and `</span>`. This one works.

```css
div#navbar.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    max-height:600px
}
nav{
    box-shadow: 15px 0px 45px #1f2021;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" 
aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About  <span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="roster.html">Roster  <span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History  <span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list">
</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="photos.html">Photos  <span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos  <span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-film"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="coaches.html">Coaches  <span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-book"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact  <span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-send"></span></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! Turns out I didn't source the two scripts at the top properly

Comment: Also try to run the code in a html validator. It will tell if you have missing end tags. You do not need to fix all the warnings always, but missing end tags can cause weird behavior in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have so many style sheets? It seems like the bootstrap stylesheet is not rendering.